# Jquery div slide across page

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/sQqzZ/

please help I'm no good with JS I tried copying and pasting these into documents but all I got was and error msg that $ is not defined. This is probably and easy fix but I'm in the dark. Could you just paste how the JS should be on here?

Comment: Well... Did you include jQuery in the HTML?

Comment: If you are using visual studio, add the jQuery file to the project and then drag and drop the file into the header of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying `$` is not defined because, the definition for `$` wasn't found on any your includes. If you are using jQuery, it means that jQuery.js file is not included.